# Docker image not getting deployed(keeps terminating) on local kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

Started working on Docker and kubernetes lately.
I ran into a problem which I don't actually understand fully.

The thing is when I execute my svc.yaml(service) and rc.yaml(replication controller) pods get created but its status is terminated.

I tried checking the possible reason for failure  by using the command

**`docker ps -a`**

> 954c3ee817f9        localhost:5000/HelloService
>   "/bin/sh -c ./startSe"   2 minutes ago       Exited (127) 2 minutes
>   ago
>   k8s_HelloService.523e3b04_HelloService-64789_default_40e92b63-707a-11e7-9b96-080027f96241_195f2fee

then tried running 
**`docker run -i -t localhost:5000/HelloService`**

> /bin/sh: ./startService.sh: not found

what is the possible reason I am getting these errors.

Docker File:

```
FROM alpine:3.2
VOLUME /tmp
ADD HelloService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
VOLUME /etc
ADD /etc/ /etc/
ADD startService.sh /startService.sh
RUN chmod 700 /startService.sh
ENTRYPOINT ./startService.sh
```

startService.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

touch /app.jar

java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xms256m -Xmx256m -jar /app.jar
```

Also I would like to know if there any specific way I can access the logs from kubernetes for the terminated pods?

Update :
on running below command

```
kubectl describe pods HelloService-522qw
```

> 24s       24s     1   {default-scheduler }                        Normal      Scheduled   Successfully
>   assigned HelloService-522qw to ssantosh.centos7   17s     17s     1   {kubelet
>   ssantosh.centos7} spec.containers{HelloService}   Normal      Created     Created
>   container with docker id b550557f4c17; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
>   17s       17s     1   {kubelet
>   ssantosh.centos7} spec.containers{HelloService}   Normal      Started     Started
>   container with docker id b550557f4c17   18s       16s     2   {kubelet
>   ssantosh.centos7} spec.containers{HelloService}   Normal      Pulling     pulling
>   image "localhost:5000/HelloService"   18s     16s     2   {kubelet
>   ssantosh.centos7} spec.containers{HelloService}   Normal      Pulled      Successfully
>   pulled image "localhost:5000/HelloService"   15s      15s     1   {kubelet
>   ssantosh.centos7} spec.containers{HelloService}   Normal      Created     Created
>   container with docker id d30b10211b1b; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
>   14s       14s     1   {kubelet
>   ssantosh.centos7} spec.containers{HelloService}   Normal      Started     Started
>   container with docker id d30b10211b1b   12s       11s     2   {kubelet
>   ssantosh.centos7} spec.containers{HelloService}   Warning     BackOff     Back-off
>   restarting failed docker container   12s      11s     2   {kubelet
>   ssantosh.centos7}                 Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping:
>   failed to "StartContainer" for "HelloService" with CrashLoopBackOff:
>   "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=HelloService
>   pod=HelloService-522qw_default(1e951b45-7116-11e7-9b96-080027f96241)"

Comment: Always good to test the image locally first in some shape or form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was there is no java as a part of alpine image.

So modified the

```
FROM alpine:3.2
```

to

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java
```

Answer (score 0):

you need jdk on the machine also need to update the Dockerfile, remove the . infront of startService.sh command. like below

```
ENTRYPOINT /startService.sh
```

this will fix this error message.

> /bin/sh: ./startService.sh: not found

Comment: this did not help. I ended up using CMD and the java command to start the service.